# click to change canvas of container div not working fiddle Jquery, html5

Tags: jquery, html

I'm drawing an image on a canvas.

**PROBLEM**

Once its done, I want to click on a button to change the canvas to another container `div`, In this case nothing happens..

When clicking a new canvas appears on the new container, but no image is attached....

What am I doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/7vZnH/1691/

```js
$("button").prop("disabled",true);
$(document).on("click",".imageToMeme",function(){
 
 $("button").prop("disabled",false);
 newStart_Scr = $(this).attr("src");
  
 //alert(newStart_Scr);
  $("#start-image").attr("src",newStart_Scr);
  
  drawMeme(); 
  });
  
 $("button").on("click",function(){
  $("#newContainer").html("<canvas id='meme' ></canvas>");
    $(".memeContainer").empty();
  

 
  
  drawMeme(); 
  });
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById('meme');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // core drawing function
 var drawMeme = function() { 
  var img = document.getElementById('start-image');
  
 
  var imgWidth = img.clientWidth;
        var imgHeight = img.clientHeight; 
  var memeWidth = 440;
  var imgRatio = memeWidth/imgWidth; 
 
  // initialize canvas element with desired dimensions
  canvas.width = memeWidth;
  canvas.height = parseInt(imgHeight*imgRatio);// alert(canvas.height)


  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    }
```

```css
.meme{opacity:0;}
.imageToMeme{height:90px;display:inline-block;}
#newContainer{height:100px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to add to canvas <br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200
" class="imageToMeme"  />

<button>
Change canvas of container
</button>
<div id="newContainer"></div>
<hr>
<div class="memeContainer">
<canvas id="meme" style="" ></canvas>
</div>

<hr>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
" id="start-image" class="meme" />
```

Comment: `var canvas = document.getElementById('meme');` - this isn’t “auto-updating” ... just because you removed the existing canvas element and replaced it with a new one with the same id, does not make this variable now magically point to that new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a canvas with the same id you need to move the element to the new container by using the append() function. You won't need to empty the old container either since append will move the item. Also if you want the canvas to have the same height and width as the container you need to manually set them

```
$("#meme").height($("#newContainer").height());
$("#meme").width($("#newContainer").width());
$("#newContainer").append($("#meme"));
```

You can find the full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7vZnH/1699/